# jQuery ajax add updated variable in data on every/any ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i have the below code to add the additional data to any ajax request made by my app, but the problem is it's working only first time when the page loads , as the application is single page ajax based application , i want to use the updated variable value inside ajaxSetup to make sure all the things work as expected but somehow it takes the old value , i know ajaxSetup setups the data for ajax call on page load. here is what my ajaxSetup looks alike:

```
var token = 'b62e0352ae559ae1d1e98f0d26604630'; // this variable updates every minute.
setInterval({
 var token = $('meta[name=token]').attr('content'); // the updates the token variable every 1 minute
},1000*60*1);
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        token: token
    }
});
```

as there is predefined token, after every minute it does update , and i just want to pick the updated value of meta tag and then use it for any ajax request made on page.
if there is any another way or correction of this code it will be very helpful.

Comment: Why not request the token when needed? like `data:{ token:function(){ return $('meta[name=token]').attr('content'); }}`

Comment: @sofl  data is not only token , it has many other keys inside it. so need to update multiple ajax requests with in addition the token value

Comment: You can still add more keys. `data:{ token:function(){...}, key1:'a',.....`, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @sofl post it as answer i will accept it. your method worked :)

Comment: @sofl post it as answer, i will accept your answer

Comment: Hi, can we have more of your code, because from this code it's normal that your CSRF token never change `$('meta[name=token]').attr('content');` is only a getter.

Comment: @MaximeK  sofl's method worked like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request the token when needed so it will be up to date each time.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        token: function(){
            return $('meta[name=token]').attr('content');
        }
    }
});
```